# very large string in memory

Tags: c#, string, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am writing a program for formatting 100s of MB String data (nearing a gig) into xml == And I am required to return it as a response to an HTTP (GET) request .

I am using a StringWriter/XmlWriter to build an XML of the records in a loop and returning the

```
using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
using (writer = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings)) //where settings are the xml props

writer.ToString()
```

during testing I saw a few --out of memory exceptions-- and quite clueless on how to find a solution? do you guys have any suggestions for a memory optimized delivery of the response?

is there a memory efficient way of encoding the data? or maybe chunking the data -- 
I just can not think of how to return it without building the whole thing into one HUGE string object

thanks

--
a few clarifications --
this is an asp .net webservices app over a gigabit ethernet link as josh noted. I am not very familiar with it so still a bit of a learning curve.

I am using XMLWriter to create the XML and create a string out of it using String

some stats --
response xml size = about 385 megs (my data size will grow very quickly to way more than this)

string object size as calculated by a memory profiler = peaked at 605MB

and thanks to everyone who responded...

Comment: 1GB of xml as a HTTP response? Really?

Comment: I am tempted to say "throw some hardware at it"(joking). 500 MB( or 350 MB or 1GB) per clients is not scalable. Maybe you could throw some more light on XML that you are generating. 

This 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528818.aspx
might help.

Comment: how insightful -- I believe this is the solution that management chose :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just stream the response to the client? XmlWriter doesn't require its underlying stream to be buffered in memory. If it's ASP.NET you can use the Response.OutputStream or if it's WCF, you can use [response streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

Comment: Josh, this is a web services project -- client requests via GET to the web method -- being new to microsoft solutions, i am not sure if it is possible and how

Comment: It's probably not possible with ASMX web services and if that's what you're using I would highly suggest moving onto WCF now before it's too difficult to redesign. You've already run into one of ASMX's limitations and there's plenty of others not just limited to performance. But with WCF you can return a Stream object and chunk the data down to the caller. It's all built-in.

Comment: thanks josh!. great inputs from all but will mark this as the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use `XmlTextWriter` wrapped around `Reponse.OutputStream` to send the XML to the client and periodically flush the response.  This way you never have to have more than a few mb in memory at any one time (at least for sending to the client).

Comment: It sounds like he's assembling the XML using string manipulation.

Comment: @SLaks, Sounds like he could be doing anything since he really didn't say.

Comment: +1. Or even wrap around the `XmlTextWriter` around a `GZipStream` wrapped around `Response.OutputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP get for 1 gig? that's a lot! Perhaps you should reconsider. 
At least gziping the output could help.

Comment: Gzipping will not help if he's still building the XML this way. The problem is not in the transfer of the data, it's the fact that it's being buffered in memory before being sent. And there is no practical limit for a HTTP GET. Especially considering you can resume interrupted downloads and we have no idea what type of network he's sending it across. Could be a gigabit ethernet!

Answer (score 2):

You should not create XML using string manipulation.

Instead, you should use the `XmlTextWriter`, `XmlDocument`, or (in .Net 3.5) `XElement` classes to build an XML tree in memory, then write it directly to `Response.OutputStream` using an `XmlTextWriter`.

Writing directly to an `XmlTextWriter` that wraps `Response.OutputStream` wil be most efficient (you'll never have an entire element tree in memory at once), but will be somewhat more complicated.

By doing it this way, you will never have a single string (or array) containing the entire object, and should thus avoid OutOfMemoryExceptions.

Comment: XmlDocument and XElement will exhibit the same (actually worse) memory issues than string manipulation! Building an XML structure that large can only be done with the XmlWriter API.

Comment: You can still get out of memory exceptions if you don't have enough contiguous memory.  Changing the approach to write to a stream seems more reasonable.

Comment: @Josh: No.  Only `String` and `Array` will allocate large blocks of _contiguous_ memory.

Comment: Well that is true but the total memory consumed will be much larger for a XmlDocument/XElement than its string builder counterpart. Either way, holding that much data in memory is just asking for a DoS attack.

Comment: @Josh: Yes, but `XmlTextWriter` can be difficult to adapt to.

Comment: No kidding. I hate that API. But when dealing with data of this size, the dev just needs to suck it up and do it the right way otherwise sh*t will just start breaking one day, usually right when you're in the middle of deploying that new billing system that's 6 months overdue.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem, hope this will help someone. My initial code was:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
string xmlString;

using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, objectData, sn); // OutOfMemoryException here
    xmlString = writer.ToString();
}
```

I ended up replaceing StringWriter with MemoryStream and this solved my problem

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.Serialize(mem, objectData, sn);
    xmlString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to return each record (or a small group of records) on their own individual GETs.